# How to ensure the implementation successfully completed in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, stored-procedures

It's my main `procedure`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[main]    
AS

BEGIN;    
    DECLARE @Start DATE,
            @End   DATE;

    SET @Start = DATEADD(DAY, -1, CONVERT(date, getdate()))
    SET @End   = DATEADD(DAY, 330, @Start) 
/*
Do something
*/    
END;
```

It's my second `procedure`:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[charge]  
AS

TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[charge_tmp]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[charge_tmp]
EXEC [dbo].main
```

I changed the main `procedure` because I need to improve performance:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[main]
            @Start DATE,
            @End   DATE;
AS

BEGIN;

/*
Do something
*/

END;
```

What is the best way to change the second procedure to load the `charge_tmp` for periods of 10 days?

I need to ensure that the implementation completed successfully when all 330 days are loaded.

Edit.:
Exemple for the second `procedure`:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[dbo].[charge_tmp]

DECLARE @cnt INT = 1, @cnt_total INT = 33;

    DECLARE @Start DATE,
            @End    DATE;

    SET @Start = DATEADD(DAY, -1, CONVERT(date, getdate()))
    SET @End    = DATEADD(DAY, 10, @Start)

WHILE @cnt <= @cnt_total
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[charge_tmp]
    EXEC [dbo].main @Start, @End 

    SET @Start = DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(date, @End))
    SET @End    = DATEADD(DAY, 9, @Start)

    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END;
```

But, i don't know if it's the best way to do.

Comment: Not clear, why do you change and what did you changed, please be more specific.

Comment: Are you asking how to pass params to `main`? Or how to proceed 10days periods serially/how to implement loop?

Comment: You can't do this by changing only the second procedure.   You would have to change the first procedure as well.

Comment: Sorry my english is bad, I need change, because I need to improve performance.
how to implement loop ensure completed successfully for all 330 days? If have any problem not commit.

Comment: are you asking how to implement loop in TSQL?

Comment: In the same sentence you stated you want to improve performance and you want to loop. If you want to improve performance you need to stop looping. The problem here is the code you didn't share where you "do something".

Comment: Updated the first post. I'm asking how to implement loop ensure completed successfully for all the date range? - Performance = reduce the number of lines that must be read

Comment: You have several temp tables, `LEFT JOIN` to big subquery, `OUTER APPLY` within it (*which both may lead to enormous number of loops) with date conversion to varchar in `where` clause... I don't think that number of rows is itself the very obstacle to the best performance. There is a lot to optimize in your queries. Start from reviewing actual execution plan of it.